# Stripe integration issue : Your card's expiration year is invalid

Tags: ios, objective-c, stripe-payments

I want to implement stripe in my application. 
I am using Credit Card Number: 4242 4242 4242 4242 Exp month :02 Exp Year:2020 for testing purpose. But it gives me error "Your card's expiration year is invalid"

Comment: Have you tried 02-2017?

Comment: how to check validation through stripe please post code also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only the last 2 digits of the expiration year are required, so send `.expMonth` = 02 and `.expYear` = 20 in your `STPCardParams`.

Comment: Hey hi.. Suddenly it started giving me 
Your card's security code is invalid. Error.. I used the same things Credit Card Number: 4242 4242 4242 4242 Cvc :123