# django-stripe error: "Your card's expiration year is invalid" when testing, no matter year entered

Tags: python, django, django-views, stripe-payments

I'm using a django-strip with a view to create a charge, and if that is successful save some local items to a db.

I'm getting an error:

```
CardError at /relevant/url
Request req_tdxeiuSSMmJi89: Your card's expiration year is invalid.
```

Originally, I had my year set to use the entire year. I tried changing this to use just the last 2 digits, and when I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41426618/stripe-integration-issue-your-cards-expiration-year-is-invalid) question, it seemed like that would fix the issue, however it has made no difference.

In my stripe dashboard, I can see what is being passed to stripe, and the error seems to be caused by the card year not being passed to stripe correctly.

From my stripe dashboard:

```
Request POST body
{
  "card": {
    "number": "************4242",
    "exp_month": "10",
    "exp_year": "0",
    "cvc": "*********"
  }
}
```

I am extending a form in my view to have fields used to process a payment, as I won't be saving that information to my db, and so those fields do not correspond to a model.

***My view:***

```
def payment_order(request):
    card_num = request.POST.get('card_num', False)
    exp_month = request.POST.get('exp_month', False)
    exp_year = request.POST.get('exp_year ', False)
    cvc = request.POST.get('cvc', False)
    email = request.POST.get('email', False)
    cart = Cart(request)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OrderPayForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():

            token = stripe.Token.create(
              card={
              "number": card_num,
              "exp_month": int(exp_month),
              "exp_year": int(exp_year),
              "cvc": cvc
               },
            )

            charge = stripe.Charge.create(
              amount=cart.item['price'],
              currency="usd",
              source=token,
              description="order for "+ email
            )

            if charge['captured'] == True:
                order = form.save()
                for item in cart:
                    OrderItem.objects.create(
                        order=order,
                        product=item['product'],
                        price=item['price'],
                    )
                return render(request, 'orders/created.html', {'order': order})
    form = OrderPayForm()
    return render(request, 'orders/create.html', {'form': form})
```

***My extended form:***

```
card_num = forms.CharField(max_length=16)
exp_month = forms.CharField(max_length=2)
exp_year = forms.CharField(max_length=2)
cvc = forms.CharField(max_length=3)

class Meta(OrderForm.Meta):
    fields = OrderForm.Meta.fields + ['card_num', 'exp_month', 'exp_year', 'cvc']
```

I am uncertain as to why this is happening, as the other fields in my form are being processed and being passed just fine. Specifically, I don't understand why exp_year is failing to pass when exp_month is being processed, passed and received without issue.

Comment: Put `print(exp_year)` after `if request.method == 'POST':` - what does it print to your console when you POST to the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> exp_year = request.POST.get('exp_year ', False)

You have an extra space after exp_year in the POST.get call.